# I cannot drag and drop file paths on cmd/powershell running with admin privileges

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

When I start my cmd or powershell console with administrative privileges, I cannot drag and drop a file on them. But I can drag and drop file on it when running with normal privileges. How can I fix this issue?

I am using Windows 10 64-bit Pro

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this answer, which sounded reasonable to me:

> this is how the UAC works. Drag- and Drop are messages. And sending messages from a program with normal rights, to an application with admin rights can cause security issue.
>
> Do Drag & Drop only work with application with the same rights (program with Admin rights to program with admin rights or program with normal rights to program with normal rights ).

Source: ["Run as Administrator" prevents drag and drop working.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/cba0e9b1-25f8-40e5-a888-1435d604f68d/quotrun-as-administratorquot-prevents-drag-and-drop-working?forum=w7itprosecurity)